# CoreBluetooth Issue on Mac

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, bluetooth, iobluetooth

I bought my current Macbook Pro new less than 6 months ago, but my instance of CBCentralManager returns `CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported` for `[centralManager state];`

My mac uses Bluetooth software version 4.0.3f12 but I can't find anything that says it supports Bluetooth LE, and I can't find any relevant documentation from Apple saying what Macs support LE. Where can I find this documentation, and if my Mac is in fact not a Bluetooth LE device, what suggestions do you have for bluetooth communications between Mac and iOS? I have an iPhone 4S with Bluetooth LE hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a old iMac with "Cambridge Silicon Radio" that does not support low energy and it gets CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported , my MBA from last year does however with a Broadcom chip and i get CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn for it, they both have version 4.0.3f12 but that is not to be confused with version 4.0 of the Bluetooth spec.

Here are the details from Bluetooth Explorer

[image]
To use CoreBluetooth you will need low energy compatible BT 4.0 chips other than that the only other api with bluetooth is GameKit

Answer (score 0):

Even the current page of tech specs on macbook pro says it has "Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR", which means no LE.  If it supported LE, it would say BT 4.0

http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_mac/family/macbook_pro
(see tab "tech specs")

Don't confuse Bluetooth software version (which is just an apple thing relating to their host stack) with Bluetooth spec numbers.

Comment: FYI, current Macbook Air does have Bluetooth 4.0, as does Mac mini